# Common volume of sphere and cylinder where diameter of cylinder does not meet spheres' end

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been trying to look for similar problems to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536964/computing-common-volume-of-sphere-and-cylinder-using-triple-integrals) where the diameter of the cylinder does not meet any end of the sphere, without luck. I have the same problem:
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 9$ but insted the cylinder is $r = 2\sin(\theta)$. I know how to integrate this as if it were the problem stated in the link above, but when I try to use the same method I cannot integrate it. I have $$z=\sqrt{9-r^2} \qquad 0\le r \le 3 \sin \theta$$ and $0\le \theta \le \pi/2$ if I multiply the integral by 4.
Does anyone have tips regarding the integration?

$V=4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2\sin \theta}r\sqrt{9-r^2}drd\theta=
\frac{-4}{3}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sqrt{(9-4\sin^2 \theta)^3}-27)d\theta$

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

The projection of the solid in $xy$ plane is 
$$
D=\{(r,\theta)\;|\; 0 \le r \le 2 \sin\theta, 0 \le \theta \le { \pi} \}
$$
Then, the lower bound for $z$ is the negative part of the sphere, that is, $z=-\sqrt{9-r^2}$, and the upper bound is $z=\sqrt{9-r^2}$
So the volume is
$$
V = \iint_D \left( \sqrt{9-r^2}-(-\sqrt{9-r^2})\right) r\; dr d\theta = 2 \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\sin \theta} r\sqrt{9-r^2} \; dr d\theta
$$

---

The integral looks hard to compute manually, so maybe you are better off in spherical coordinates.

The sphere has equation $\rho=3$, and the cylinder $\rho=2 \frac{\sin \theta}{\sin \phi}$. Both intersect at
$$
\phi_0 = \sin^{-1}\left( \frac{2\sin \theta}{3}\right)
$$
It follows that the volume equals
$$
V=2 \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\phi_0}\int_{\rho=0}^{3}\rho^2 \sin\phi \; d\rho d\phi d \theta + 2 \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}\int_{\phi=\phi_0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\rho=0}^{2 \frac{\sin \theta}{\sin \phi}}\rho^2 \sin\phi \; d\rho d\phi d \theta
$$